# Erro com persistence.xml e EclipseLink no glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, persistência, eclipse-link

Olá pessoal estou com esse problema depois que migrei o projeto para outra maquina, estou utilizando GlassFish com EclipseLink na base de dados utilizo o Postgres 9.4 se alguém já se deparou com esse erro poderia me ajudar não consegui resolver.

Já refiz toda a configuração e me deparo com mesmo erro.

> "Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
>   'PostgresDB'"

**Console:**

```
 Informações:   [EL Info]: 2015-11-04 02:44:01.713--ServerSession(1551564778)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
    Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
    javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:98)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:258)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:237)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:174)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:170)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:84)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:77)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:71)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.executeSafely(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:61)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:71)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler$1.call(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.executeSafely(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:68)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:61)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:90)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:271)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:258)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:237)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:174)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:170)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:84)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.ratossi.portifolio.model.Persistence.ArtesaoDAOJPA.salvar(ArtesaoDAOJPA.java:19)
        at com.ratossi.portifolio.controllers.CadastroController.save(CadastroController.java:33)
        at com.ratossi.portifolio.controllers.CadastroController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
        at net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider.invoke(DefaultReflectionProvider.java:42)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultReflectionProvider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod$1.call(ExecuteMethod.java:82)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod$1.call(ExecuteMethod.java:72)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.Try.run(Try.java:18)
        at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:90)
        ... 77 more
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
    Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [PostgresDB].
    Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'PostgresDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PostgresDB not found]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at com.ratossi.portifolio.model.dao.Facabrica.<clinit>(Facabrica.java:20)
        ... 97 more
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
    Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [PostgresDB].
    Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'PostgresDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PostgresDB not found]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
        ... 105 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'PostgresDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PostgresDB not found]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:622)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
        ... 110 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PostgresDB not found
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
        ... 115 more

    Informações:   [EL Severe]: ejb: 2015-11-04 02:44:01.715--ServerSession(1551564778)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
    Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [PostgresDB].
    Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'PostgresDB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: PostgresDB not found]
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.ratossi_portifolio_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>PostgresDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.ratossi.portifolio.model.Artesanato</class>
    <class>com.ratossi.portifolio.model.Artesao</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**glassfish-resources.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="post-gre-sql_portifolio_postgresPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="portifolio"/>
        <property name="User" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="Password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portifolio"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>

    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="PostgresDB" object-type="user" pool-name="post-gre-sql_portifolio_postgresPool"/>
</resources>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <groupId>com.ratossi</groupId>
    <artifactId>portifolio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>portifolio</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0-RC2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: No glassfish todos os recursos JNDI estão em `java:comp/env` e o padrão quando você publica um JDBC é que inicie com `jdbc`, então no seu caso, para manter o padrão, use `jdbc/PostgresDB`. Caso não possa, teste no seu `persistence.xml` usar `java:comp/env/PostgresDB` ou também `java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgresDB`. Veja o log do servidor também, ele lista os recursos ao iniciar.

Comment: Fiz as mudanças que você falou, mas continuou com o mesmo erro.

Comment: E existe o recurso no glassfish? Se não existe, não está sendo publicado. Verificou no log e no console de administração?

Comment: Irei verifica o Log, devo procura por `java:comp/env` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu acabei achando uma solução simples para este problema.

Este erro ocorre devido alguns bugs no Glassfish 4.1 que já vem com Netbeans,a solução simples e você baixa direto do [Site do GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) a versão instável.
Espero ajudar aqueles que tenha o mesmo problema que eu.
Obrigado um bom dia a todos.